# Liquid + Jekyll, "unless" not working inside "for" loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm making JSON given a set of pages. I want to skip any pages without titles, and the last element can not have a comma after it, that's bad JSON. Tried different variations, here is an example:

```
---
---
[
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% unless page.title %}
        {% continue %}
    {% else %}
{
"title":"{{ page.title }}",
"content":"{{ page.content | strip_html | strip_newlines }}",
"href":"{{ page.url }}"
}
    {% endunless %}
    {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

The end of the resulting JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"title":"Test Search",
"content":" ",
"href":"/search.html"
}

    ,



]
```

How do I get rid of the trailing comma? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your last loop iteration is one that has no title.

Try to prepend the comma. That way you don't have to look in the future:

```
{% assign isFirst = true %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% unless page.title %}{% continue %}{% endunless %}
    {% unless isFirst %},{% endunless %}
    {% assign isFirst = false %}
    {
    "title": {{ page.title | jsonify  }},
    "content": {{ page.content | strip_html | strip_newlines | jsonify  }},
    "href": {{ page.url | jsonify  }}
    }
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: You should also use the `jsonify` filter to ensure proper escaping of quotes and other characters.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the last loop iterations(s), thought I'd addressed that in another variation but I was mistaken. But the code you posted does not add commas. Let me try and fix ....

Comment: @user3213137 your right. For some reason I decided to add the assign statement into the unless block which (of course) doesn't work. I changed that now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using {% raw %} to escape your non-liquid brackets, this can cause Jekyll to misbehave without throwing any errors.

If that still leads to odd behavior try creating a seperate array like the following example, which is very similar to the case from OP.

```
{% assign suggestions = "" | split: ',' %}
{%- for item in site[page.collection] -%}
{%- unless item.url == page.url -%}
{% assign suggestions = suggestions | push: item %}
{%- endunless -%}
{%- endfor -%}
<script id="suggest-json" type="application/json">
[
{%- for item in suggestions -%}
    {% assign images = item.media | where: "type", "image" %}
    {% assign image = images.first %}
    {% raw %}
    {
    {% endraw %}
        "url": "{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}",
        "title": {{ item.title | jsonify }},
        "subject": {{ item.game | jsonify }},
        "image": {{ image.thumbnail | jsonify }},
        "alt": {{ image.thumbnail_alt | jsonify }}
    {% raw %}
    }
    {% endraw %}
    {%- unless forloop.last -%},{%- endunless -%}
{%- endfor -%}
]
</script>
```

The problem may be that Jekyll doesn't actually consider the forloop.index as last because it isn't technically. You can avoid this by creating a new array either with a loop or the 'where' tag (loop used above).

The forloop.last should now behave properly, hope this helps.